# Render games with custom resolution at native resolution?

Tags: windows-10, display, resolution, nvidia-graphics-card, alt-tab

I'm playing a game on a custom resolution (lower than the native one), while also on fullscreen and no stretching, in other words, letterboxing.
I did that with the Nvidia settings but the problem comes when I alt-tab, it takes way too long, usually 2-3 secs, I know it's short but for a supposedly quick task such as alt-tabbing it really is tedious.
I've seen an option in Osu! that lets you "render game at full resolution" which results in a letterbox like I stated earlier but this time, alt-tabbing is as fast as playing on fullscreen.
I was wondering is there any way you can achieve this on windows 10, and on any game? Thanks.

Comment: Are you only using one display with your machine?

Comment: @KalamalkaKid Yes. a 2560x1080p display and I play all games on the custom res 1920x1080p.

Comment: Is your display switching resolution when you are alt-tabbing? Is the game running in a different resolution to the desktop ?

Comment: @KalamalkaKid Yes I think that's the reason alt tabbing takes too long, it changes the resolution back to the native one.

Comment: yes that is your problem then. Im not sure what to suggest other than ruuning your game in the same as your desktop, or try windowed moded and see if that works.